# process some iterations on python ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy, multidimensional-array

I created two sorted ndarrays of the same length and joined them via vstack().
I refer to my array in the following as:

```
[[x1 y1][x2 y2][x3 y3][x4 y4]].
```

However, in reality I have a different value for `x` in every entry but only a few different values for `y` ascending from 0 to `n`.

So I got something like this:

```
[[x1 0],[x2 0],[x3 0],[x4 1],[x5 1],[x6 2],[x7 2],[x8 2][x9 3][x10 3]...]
```

My goal is to create a loop to get every first and last x-value for all the different y-values. So that the loop returns `x1` and `x3` (`y == 0`), `x4` and `x5` (`y == 1`), `x6` and `x8` (`y == 2`) and so on.

I am trying an ugly solution for this at the moment, creating sub arrays for all the different y-values, so that I can take the first and last element of each array to get the y-values I need but I was wondering what the most effective or pythonic way to achieve this would look like.

Comment: Show us the ugly way; that'll make it easier to suggest improvements.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in using 2 list comprehension. At the first one you can use `itertools.groupby()` in order to grouping your sub lists based on their second elements then choose the first and last item.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> 
>>> groups = [list(g) for _, g in groupby(lst, key=itemgetter(1))]
>>> 
>>> [sub if len(sub)<2 else [sub[0], sub[-1]] for sub in groups]
[[['x1', 0], ['x3', 0]], [['x4', 1], ['x5', 1]], [['x6', 2], ['x8', 2]], [['x9', 3], ['x10', 3]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A `default_dict` is a nice way of collecting values like this

define the array (wish I could simply have copy-n-pasted):

```
In [186]: A=np.array([[1, 0],[2, 0],[3, 0],[4 ,1],[5 ,1],[6, 2],[7, 2],[8 ,2],[9 ,3],[10 ,3]])
In [187]: A
Out[187]: 
array([[ 1,  0],
       [ 2,  0],
       [ 3,  0],
       [ 4,  1],
       [ 5,  1],
       [ 6,  2],
       [ 7,  2],
       [ 8,  2],
       [ 9,  3],
       [10,  3]])
```

Make the dictionary, default value of `list()`, and append the array row:

```
In [188]: from collections import defaultdict
In [189]: dd = defaultdict(list)
In [190]: for row in A:
   .....:     dd[row[1]].append(row)
   .....:     
In [191]: dd
Out[191]: defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {0: [array([1, 0]), array([2, 0]), array([3, 0])], 1: [array([4, 1]), array([5, 1])], 2: [array([6, 2]), array([7, 2]), array([8, 2])], 3: [array([9, 3]), array([10,  3])]})
```

I can extract the 1st and last values into another dictionary:

```
In [192]: {key:[value[0],value[-1]] for key,value in dd.items()}
Out[192]: 
{0: [array([1, 0]), array([3, 0])],
 1: [array([4, 1]), array([5, 1])],
 2: [array([6, 2]), array([8, 2])],
 3: [array([9, 3]), array([10,  3])]}
```

Or I could have collected values in lists, etc., or a 3d array

```
In [195]: np.array([np.array([value[0],value[-1]]) for key,value in dd.items()]) 
Out[195]: 
array([[[ 1,  0],
        [ 3,  0]],

       [[ 4,  1],
        [ 5,  1]],

       [[ 6,  2],
        [ 8,  2]],

       [[ 9,  3],
        [10,  3]]])
```

`itertools.groupby` is nice, and may be faster.  But you need to be comfortable with generators.

If the `y` values are sorted, you could find the values where value changes, and use those indices to split the array.